# How to display the selected item in row in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a a dropdown component that allows user to select the language they desired. When the item is selected, the image and the text should be displayed in a row. The problem is that the selected item is displayed vertically. I tried using `flexDirection: 'row'` on the `Select` component and `MenuItem` component, but it didnt work.

```
<Box sx={{width: '100%'}}> 
    <Select sx={{width: '160px'}} defaultValue={1}>
        <MenuItem sx={{gap: 1}} value={1}>
            <Avatar src={UK} sx={{width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
            English
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem sx={{gap: 1}} value={2}>
            <Avatar src={Malaysia} sx={{width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
            Malay
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem sx={{gap: 1}} value={3}>
            <Avatar src={China} sx={{width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
            Mandarin
        </MenuItem>
    </Select>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Need to wrapped the child component of `MenuItem`.

```
<MenuItem key={index} value={item.langCode} onClick={() => changeLang(item.langCode)}>
    <Box sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', gap: 1}}>
        <Avatar src={item.flag} sx={{width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
        {item.title}
    </Box> 
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Stack for the same.

Here, is the full code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          </Stack>

          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Stack>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Let me know, if you have any questios.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Box sx={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Select sx={{ width: '160px' }} defaultValue={1}>
    <MenuItem sx={{ gap: 1, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }} value={1}>
      <Avatar src={UK} sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
      English
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem sx={{ gap: 1, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }} value={2}>
      <Avatar src={Malaysia} sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
      Malay
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem sx={{ gap: 1, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }} value={3}>
      <Avatar src={China} sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
      Mandarin
    </MenuItem>
  </Select>
</Box>
```

I added display: 'flex' and flexDirection: 'row' to the MenuItem components to make sure they are displayed horizontally. The Box component with display: 'flex' is used to wrap the MenuItem elements.

Let me know, if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome! And, thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow! This is just a note to help you improve your (future) answers. Stack Overflow recommends that you begin with a summary or an explanation of your code before presenting the code block. This helps to provide some context to the code that follows. You can edit your answer accordingly if you wish. Thanks.